# Trying RSepc for the first time with no luck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I finally want to add real testing to my Rails app and using various tutorials to learn. This github page - https://gist.github.com/kyletcarlson/6234923 - 
has some great boiler plate examples and I think I'm following it correctly but can't get it to work. I get the following error:

```
// ♥ rspec
2019-07-21 15:04:37 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
F

Failures:

  1) Employee should have many :employee_projects
     Failure/Error: it {expect(Employee).to have_many(:employee_projects)}
       expected Employee to respond to `has_many?`
     # ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00687 seconds (files took 1.21 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb:5 # Employee should have many :employee_projects

[15:04:37] (rev2) Esto
// ♥ rpsec
bash: rpsec: command not found
[15:25:58] (rev2) Esto
// ♥ rspec
2019-07-21 15:26:02 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
FF

Failures:

  1) Employee ActiveRecord Association tests 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(employee).to have_many(:employee_projects) }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `employee' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Employee::ActiveRecordAssociationTests:0x00007fc28c60c470>
     # ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Employee ActiveRecord Association tests 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(employee).to have_many(:projects).through(:employee_projects)}

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `employee' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Employee::ActiveRecordAssociationTests:0x00007fc28c614f80>
     # ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00482 seconds (files took 1.11 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb:6 # Employee ActiveRecord Association tests 
rspec ./spec/models/employee_spec.rb:7 # Employee ActiveRecord Association tests
```

Here is my `User` model:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :employee_projects
    has_many :projects, through: :employee_projects
end
```

and here is my rspec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Employee, type: :model do
  describe 'ActiveRecord Association tests' do 
    it { expect(employee).to have_many(:employee_projects) }  
    it { expect(employee).to have_many(:projects).through(:employee_projects)}
  end 
end
```

and my Gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server

gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0' 

gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'activerecord-import'

gem 'phonelib'


# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'webdrivers', '~> 3.0'

group :development, :test do

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do

  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'

  # gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:development, :test]
```

Do I have rspec installed correctly? Not sure about what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec is actually telling you exactly what the problem is.In your test `employee` is not defined

> NameError:
>          undefined local variable or method `employee

```
it { expect(employee).to have_many(:employee_projects) }
```

This assertion is testing undefined variable to have_many employee projects. You would have to either define employee or just do a different test (testing active record association dosen't make much sense, you can assume active record is working and well tested).

Comment: I also realized that I was missing some Gems for this particular boiler plate:  shoulda-matchers, shoulda-callbacks, and factory_girl_rails.